# xpath is not working, i need a unique id to identify the element

Tags: java, xml, selenium

[image]

i need a unique id to identify the text field(start - press)(end - press) mention in the below image
there is no id, name or class to identify them[image]

this is the xml code seen in inspect element.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

//input[contains(@placeholder,'Start')] 
or 
//div[@class="leaflet-routing-geocode"]/input

Comment: i use it as a id or xpath?

Comment: That will be xpath

Comment: no it is not working

Answer (score 0):

i think

> By.cssSelector("input[placeholder=\"Start - press enter to drop
>   marker\"]")

...ought to work

Comment: it is not working, there is an integration of two pages that's why it is not working i.e., one page on another page and the upper image is that one page.